# Как загрузить изменения?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, хостинг, filezilla

Я выставил сайт, написанный на React с помощью FileZilla, на хостинг и после внес изменения, которые не отображаются на сайте. Я снова попытался сделать, запустил `npm build`, но изменения не перешли на сайт. Подскажите, как вносятся изменения в таком случае?

Comment: Где вы запустили `npm run build`? Вы сбросили кеш в своём браузере?

Comment: Кстати, у меня был тот же вопрос, просто он задан не совсем понятно. Реакт предложение создаётся чере ран билд и загружается на сервер. После, внося изменения у себя, хочешь добавить эти изменения на сайт, но там уже другие файлы. Я, кроме как перезаливать полностью на сайт, выход не нашел...